# line-height = font-size + 30px

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an `h1`, I want to use clamp for its font-size
The `line-height` should be `calc((fs / 100 * 30px) + fs)`
fs is the font-size of the h1
if the fs = 100 then it should be `calc((100 / 100 * 30px) + 100px)`
but how to do that in css?

Comment: Can you show us ow you are setting the font-size for the h1?

Comment: I did:
`font-size: clamp(15px, 3vw, 50px)`

Answer (score 0):

The question asks how to set the line-height to 30px more than the font-size.

We know the font-size, which is defined by a CSS clamp. This snippet creates a CSS variable --fs with this value and uses it with a CSS calc to increase it by 30px for the line-height.

```css
div {
  --fs: clamp(15px, 3vw, 50px);
  font-size: var(--fs);
  line-height: calc(var(--fs) + 30px);
}
```

```html
<div>HELLO<br>GOODBYE</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the line height should be `calc((var(--fs) / 100 * 40px) + var(--fs))`, but css can't do (100px / 100), so the first `var(--fs)` should be 100 instead of 100px

Comment: That can’t be done in CSS. How about the line height becoming the font size plus a fraction of the font size. That would seem to  make sense and scale well.